# Unrecognized token '$context': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') AWS VTL

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am passing a header called `context-token` via a graphql client and I am trying to pull it out of the headers to pass to a lambda using the following vtl:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "type": "Query",
        "resolver": "apiContext",
        "arguments":  $utils.toJson($context.arguments),
        "contextToken": $context.request.headers.context-token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "type": "Query",
        "resolver": "apiContext",
        "arguments":  $utils.toJson($context.arguments),
        "contextToken": "$context.request.headers.get("context-token")"
    }
}
```